# How many (usable) serial ports does Pi Zero 2 W have?

Tags: serial, uart, pi-zero-w-2

The Raspberry Pi 1, 2, 3 and Pi Zero / Zero W all have **two** UARTs (PL011 + mini UART). The Raspberry Pi 4 and 400 have **six** UARTs (5 x PL011 + mini UART). This is from the [official documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-uarts).

I have been unable to find information about the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W. There is however a difference between Zero W (Buster) versus Zero 2 W (Bullseye) when I run *dtoverlay*.

```
pi@rpi-zero-w:~ $ dtoverlay -a | grep uart
  midi-uart0
  midi-uart1
  miniuart-bt
  uart0
  uart1
  uart2
  uart3
  uart4
  uart5
```

```
pi@rpi-zero-2-w:~ $ dtoverlay -a | grep uart
  midi-uart0
  midi-uart1
  midi-uart2
  midi-uart3
  midi-uart4
  midi-uart5
  miniuart-bt
  qca7000-uart0
  uart0
  uart1
  uart2
  uart3
  uart4
  uart5
```

Does this mean that the Zero 2 W also has 6 UARTs?
Can I map some of these out to GPIO pins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Pi Zero2 W has the same BCM2710A1 SOC as the Pi3 and all pre Pi4 models have the same peripheral implementation, so the same UART.

`dtoverlay -a` lists all defined device-tree overlays, but none of these are loaded.

In my experience `dtoverlay -l` doesn't show any loaded, even though I have a few.